# unordered_map of boost::dynamic_bitset slower when compiled with 64-bit

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, unordered-map, boost-dynamic-bitset

I'm having an interesting performance issue.

I'm working on Windows, in Visual Studio 2015.

I've got a program that relies currently on Boost's dynamic bitsets. When I compile it as a 32-bit program, it runs fine and quickly. But it is massively slower when I compile it as a 64-bit program.

After profiling, the following functions go from taking almost no time to 69% and 22% respectively:

`lower_bound`:

```
std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<VSet,int,std::_Uhash_compare<VSet,std::hash<VSet>,std::equal_to<VSet> >,std::allocator<std::pair<VSet const ,int> >,0> >::lower_bound
```

`_Insert`:

```
std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<VSet,int,std::_Uhash_compare<VSet,std::hash<VSet>,std::equal_to<VSet> >,std::allocator<std::pair<VSet const ,int> >,0> >::_Insert<std::pair<VSet const ,int> & __ptr64,std::_List_unchecked_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::pair<VSet const ,int> > > > >
```

Both are defined in `include/xhash`, a Visual C++ header library. However, I'm suspicious of the dynamic bitset, since they're what is being hashed.

The `VSet` type they're referring to is a shallow wrapper around `boost::dynamic_bitset`, that I wrote, with a hash function defined as follows:

```
namespace std {
    template <> struct hash<VSet>
    {
        size_t operator()(const VSet & S) const
        {
            return boost::hash_value(S.bitVec.m_bits);
        }
    };
}
```

A couple interesting details:

- The same performance issue doesn't happen with Clang on Linux. I haven't been able to test it with Clang on Windows yet.
- As far as I can see, I'm using the same Optimizer settings for x86 and x64.

#### My Question:

- Are there known "Gotchas" with using either `unordered_map` or `boost::dynamic_bitset` with 64-bit? In particular, since dynamic bitset is doing some bit-twiddling stuff.
- Is there a specific optimizer setting in VS that I should be tweaking to try to avoid this?
- Might there be something I have to do differently when compiling the Boost libraries to prevent this?

Comment: What makes it a performance bug? It's just a property of "compiler architecture" + "code-generation". I'd amend the wording there. Interesting to know wheter someone spots the problem on MSVC

Comment: It's an issue, not a bug I guess. But it seems that switching from x86 to x64 with no changes to code should produce at least a similar performance profile, albeit not identical.

Comment: Seems you could dig deeper without too much effort - `lower_bound` on the `VSet` has nothing to do with the hashing or `unordered_map`; just doing some profiling directly of the `dynamic_bitset` operation should still show the performance difference, but it's worth confirming.

Comment: VSet is just a shallow wrapper around `dynamic_bitset`, and its hash function is just hashing the bitset.